# AdjustToContents so that scrollbar is not on top of data

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt5

I have a table with a varying number of rows and columns and I'd want to adjust the size of the table so that there is no extra white space.

What I've tried to do is:

`myTable.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContentsOnFirstShow)`

This works well but if the window is fixed or there are too many rows to show. Then suddenly there will be scrollbars that appear and block the view of some of the table data. I would want the scrollbars to be to the side of the table and not on top it.

Comment: Would that work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947977/how-do-i-get-rid-of-this-whitespace-in-my-qtablewidget ?

Comment: Fantastic! It automatically shrinks the last row/column so the scrollbar can fit in. Sorry for the very late response. You can post this as an answer!